# One page vertical other pages horizontal

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report (PDF) that shows some inventory that belongs to our department. This is how my report looks like. MyTablix1 show the department info MyTablix2 shows the inventory.

```
---------------------
|                   |
|    MyTablix1      |
|    ---------      |
|    |       |      |
|    ---------      |
|                   |
|    MyTablix2      |
|    ---------      |
|    |       |      |
|    ---------      |
|                   |
---------------------
```

but what I want to do is my first page should be vertical and show only MyTablix1 which is department info. and second page should be horizontal and MyTablix2 should be using the left side and the right side of the page as shown below.

```
---------------------
|                   |
|    MyTablix1      |
|    ---------      |
|    |       |      |
|    ---------      |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
---------------------

---------------------------------
|                               |
|    MyTablix2      MyTablix2   |
|    ---------      ---------   |
|    |       |      |       |   |
|    ---------      ---------   |
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bad news for you. Afaik **this is not possible** in SSRS. Page dimensions are a property of the report itself, you can not change those halfway into the content.

The "easiest" workaround I can see is first render (e.g. to PDF) the portait bit from report 1, then render the second report in landscape, and do custom post-processing to join the two documents together.

Comment: I tried couple of things but no luck. I guess there is no way to achieve it.